# Bat file fails when file name has spaces

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have this batch file that process some video files in a batch. Things work just fine as long as the filename has no white spaces in it's name. If the file name (test movie.avi) has white space it says

> test: No such file or directory

So it seems it is treating the space as a separator. How do I get around this problem?

```
for %%a in (%1\*.avi) do (
   ffmpeg -i %%a -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart -preset slow -crf 22 -b:v 500k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k "%2/%%~na.mp4" -vf select="not(mod(n\,10))"
)
```

This is how I call this:

```
Process.bat C:\FFMPEG\inputfiles C:\FFMPEG\outputfiles
```

Comment: I found the solution!

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer in order to help future visitors to the site who might have the same problem.

Comment: I've never understood why people mention that they found a solution but do not actually provide the solution.

Comment: -1  as you well know this is nothing to do with ffmpeg. Any program will fail if a file has spaces and no quotes. try notepad a b c .txt   will not open that file.  This question is no use to anybody ffmpeg in the title is irrelevant. You did no troubleshooting.

Comment: i've decided to retain the -1 I gave you(even after somebody edited the title for you), this time because you didn't bother to look up how to preserve spaces in a filename. It's jokingly easy to look that up.

Answer (score 3):

You need some quotes around your %%a in the invocation of ffmpeg.

~Edit: Added Modified Script

```
for %%a in (%1\*.avi) do (
   ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart -preset slow -crf 22 -b:v 500k -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k "%2/%%~na.mp4" -vf select="not(mod(n\,10))"
)
```